# tmux 2.6 copy and paste

Tags: mouse, tmux

I used to be able to use mouse to highlight a region for copy and paste. ( `set -g mouse on` has always been in my `~/.tmux.conf`)

But after a recent upgrade to tmux 2.6, it does not allow me to do so anymore.

There are discussions that may be relevant here and there. But no tmux version numbers are provided. Due to the syntax changes in tmux in the last few versions, I am not sure these suggestions are relevant to 2.6.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318281/how-to-successfully-copy-and-paste-with-a-mouse-from-tmux

Does anybody know how to allow me copy and paste (using mouse) with `set -g mouse on` enabled in tmux 2.6?

Comment: Have you tried an empty .tmux.conf file with only the mouse support enabled? Have you tried highlighting text and pressing "y" to yank? When you say "copy" do you mean to the tmux clipboard (paste with Control-]), or the OS clipboard? Please provide your OS details.